# How to get video codec properties of video?

Tags: android, codec

I need to extract the codec properties like bit rate frames resolution file format of video  captures from camcorder.

Comment: yes.. after capturing the video i need to retrive the video properties.

Answer (score 2):

Check out https://ffmpeg.org/,
https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg#22-android

One way would be: `ffmpeg -i myfile.mp4`

Answer (score 1):

ffprobe can used to list the properties of streams available in the video.

```
ffprobe -i <input_file_path> -show_streams
```

Above command list codec properties such as codec_name, codec_long_name, codec_type etc., of each stream individually.

Refer this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708373/get-ffmpeg-information-in-friendly-way) for more info.

https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android - FFMpeg/FFprobe compiled for Android.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider GStreamer, please see `gst-discover-1.0`
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/gstreamer-tools.html#gstdiscoverer10

Answer (score -1):

You can using Termux in android for get codec properties of video after recorded.

1. Install Termux App [GooglePlay](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux)
2. Install the FFmpeg package
   Open the Termux app from the launcher. You will be introduced to a console environment.
   Enter the following command:

> pkg install -y ffmpeg

Show codec properties:

> ffmpeg -i yourfile