# Android Mediaplayer.Trackinfo getFormat() is not defined

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a media player in my android app. I have to find the codecs used in the file that is played by this media player. I have the following code.

```
TrackInfo[] ti = mediaplayer.getTrackInfo();
    MediaFormat mf;
    for (int i = 0; i<ti.length;i++){
        if(ti[i].getTrackType() == TrackInfo.MEDIA_TRACK_TYPE_AUDIO)
        {
            mf = ti[i].getFormat();
        }
    }
```

But, I get an error saying "The method getFormat() is undefined for the type MediaPlayer.TrackInfo". But it can be seen [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.TrackInfo.html#getFormat%28%29) that there is indeed a function. I am able to call getTrackType, but not getFormat. What is the reason?

Comment: That method was introduced in API19. Are you testing on device with lower API?

Comment: Oops. Yes. Is there any other way I can find the codec used in the video being played?

Comment: I don't know that. But maybe the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034995/how-to-get-video-codec-properties-of-video) might help.

Comment: Hi, that helps in reading the MIME type. But, I would like to get more details, like video codec type, bitrate, audio codec, audio bitrate etc. Please let me know if you know of any.